# How to provide write permissions to the data directory when deploying Node-red on Azure IoT edge device?

Tags: docker, node-red, azure-iot-edge

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3
Debian GNU/Linux
ARM32v7

**Dear community members,**

I am trying to install Node-Red module on Azure IoT Edge device as it described in https://github.com/iotblackbelt/noderededgemodule.
However, I am facing the following problem: there is no permission for the node-red container. I tried to start docker image of node-red, though it didn't work. As I understood I need to give permission to the docker container. How to do it?

I receive the following logs:

```
> node-red-docker@1.1.3 start /usr/src/node-red
> node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js $FLOWS "--userDir" "/data"

internal/fs/utils.js:269
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/settings.js' -> '/data/settings.js'
    at Object.copyFileSync (fs.js:1882:3)
    at copyFile (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:68:8)
    at onFile (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:53:25)
    at getStats (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:48:44)
    at startCopy (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:38:10)
    at handleFilterAndCopy (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:33:10)
    at Object.copySync (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/copy-sync.js:26:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/red.js:125:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/settings.js',
  dest: '/data/settings.js'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-red-docker@1.1.3 start: `node $NODE_OPTIONS node_modules/node-red/red.js $FLOWS "--userDir" "/data"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-red-docker@1.1.3 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Not for docker.I think you have to give permission to host file?

Comment: You need to edit the question to include the `docker run` command you use to start the container

Comment: Also any reason you are using 1.1.3 and not 3.0.2?

Comment: @hardillb Docker version 20.10.18+azure-1

Comment: I didn't ask for the version of Docker (the second question was why are you using such an out of date Node-RED container. 1.1.3 is truly ancient), I asked for details of how you are starting the container, because that will have the details of the local directory path that is getting mounted on `/data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important bit that should have been in the question appears to be

```
    "Binds": [
        "/node-red:/data"
    ],
```

This implies that the directory `/node-red` is mounted in `/data`

You need to ensure that uid 1000 can write to this. The quickest way is probably to run:

```
sudo chown 1000:1000 /node-red
```

Comment: Hello, @hardillb, thanks for the answer. Now I have similar problem with the node for virtual machine on windows (EFLOW - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-for-linux-on-windows?view=iotedge-2018-06). For the raspberry pi I have changed this Binds to "/home/pi/node-red:/data" to make it work, and for the EFLOW to "/home/iotedge-user/node-red:/data".  What do you think could be a problem?

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question.