# Can I run Node-Red under docker on VM EFLOW (Azure IoT edge on windows Device)?

Tags: azure, docker, node-red, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I deployed node-red container aka "IoT edge device module" (nodered/node-red:latest) on an Azure IoT edge device installed on Linux VM on Windows device ([EFLOW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart?view=iotedge-2018-06)) based on my experience doing it according to [node-red deployment on IoT edge device on Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/noderededgemodule).

Unfortunately, I face the problem with the following error logs:

```
    Error: EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/settings.js' -> '/data/settings.js'
    at Object.copyFileSync (node:fs:2817:3)
    at copyFile (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:73:6)
    at onFile (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:59:25)
    at getStats (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:51:44)
    at handleFilterAndCopy (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:36:10)
    at Object.copySync (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/copy-sync.js:29:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/red.js:129:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'copyfile',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/usr/src/node-red/node_modules/node-red/settings.js',
  dest: '/data/settings.js'
}
```

Similar problem I faced during deployment of a node-red on IoT edge device on Raspberry Pi. I solved it with the help of community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73864836/how-to-provide-write-permissions-to-the-data-directory-when-deploying-node-red-o/73866691?noredirect=1#comment131445482_73866691). I repeated the same things for the EFLOW (VM on Windows), but it didn't work. Practically, I fixed the "Binds":

```
"Binds": [
            "/home/iotedge-user/node-red:/data"
        ],
```

I also described the problem [here](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/node-red-does-not-run-on-iot-edge-module-on-a-windows-device/70641), though I didn't get any decent help.

Furthermore, as [node-red docker](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/docker) is for specific architectures (amd64, arm32v6, arm32v7, arm64v8 and s390x), I also thought I have problems due my system which is:

```
Virtualization: microsoft
Operating System: CBL-Mariner/Linux
Kernel: Linux 5.15.67.1-4.cm2
Architecture: x86-64
Hardware Vendor: Microsoft Corporation
Hardware Model: Virtual Machine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this has nothing to do with the CPU architecture (x86-64 is the same as amd64) and the container wouldn't even start if you didn't have a matching CPU arch.

The problem here is the file permissions on the host OS, in this case most likely the Linux instance in the VM.

As I described in your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73864836/how-to-provide-write-permissions-to-the-data-directory-when-deploying-node-red-o/73866691?noredirect=1#comment131445482_73866691), what ever path on the host (in this case `/home/iotedge-user/node-red`) that is mounted on `/data` in the container needs to be writeable by the uid 1000. How you set that depends on what access you have to the host OS. But assuming you can get a terminal on the host OS then you would run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /home/iotedge-user/node-red
```

This may prompt for your users password to grant sudo access.